# Sharepoint :How to copy data from Oracle to Sharepoint List on some interval?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am using SharePoint 2013 and want to copy data from Oracle Db to SharePoint List on some interval?

What could be the best possible way to do this,Can anyone give me the suggestion?

Comment: Use the same technique SP itself uses to do things regularly: Timer Jobs

Comment: Is this not possible from Business connectivity Service?

Answer (score 0):

We can connect  BCS to the oracle

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff464424(v=office.14).aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-connect-to-the-oracle-database-using-business-connectivity-services-bcs-in-sharepoint-2010/